# Switching twig library to symfony's TwigEngine

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I have a functional php-twig website. Now I'm trying to run this website on the symfony2 framework.

Currently I'm trying to do the template processing using symfony's TwigEngine (via the render method).

The website currently instantiates a twigenvironment to process the templates, but it uses the renderblock function for some of the processing :
here is some of the code used to render the template.$twig is a twig_environment.

I know it is not very little written and might not help much.

The code is really scattered so I couldn't get all the relevant parts.

Please comment regarding information on any part of it and I'll try to extract it from the code.

```
if ($type == 'file') {
    $template = $twig->loadTemplate($data);
    $GLOBALS['twigCurrentLoadedTemplate'] = &$template;
    $result = $template->render($params);
} elseif ($type == 'block') {
    if (isset($GLOBALS['twigTemplateBlocks']) && 
    isset($GLOBALS['twigTemplateBlocks'][$data['name']])) {
        $template = $twig->loadTemplate($GLOBALS['twigTemplateBlocks'][$data['name']]);
    } elseif (!isset($data['template'])) {
        $template = $GLOBALS['twigCurrentLoadedTemplate'];
    } else {
        $template = &$data['template'];//$twig->loadTemplate($data['file']);
    }
    $params['blockNameToRender'] = $data['name'];
    $result = $template->renderBlock($data['name'], $params);
}
```

If the code is just too useless, some information on general on renderblock and render methods would be nice and how, you can convert some hypothetical code or template to use render instead of renderblock.

Update: I've found out that the renderblock method is used for creating ajax responses e.g: creating a "create new message page".

Comment: Why are you using `$GLOBALS` for any of this???

Comment: The current setting of everything is stored as global variables as you.in this case instead of passing the blocknames as parameters to the function it is stored as global variables.Which I know is not good practise at all.